# dbLinq Sqlite select from multiple databases

Tags: linq, sqlite, dblinq

I'm not able to find any answer to my problem. I have two database, local and custom, and I need to join certain tables from both DBs between them. But I'm getting errors as for example "No such table PcApplicationsComponents".

My code is:

```
using (SqliteCustomDb.Custom customDbCon = Sqlite.SqliteConnection.GetCustomDbConnection())
{
using (SqliteLocalDb.Local localDbCon = Sqlite.SqliteConnection.GetLocalDbConnection())
    {
        var localCompss = from lc in localDbCon.Components
                          join c in customDbCon.PcApplicationsComponents
                            on lc.ID equals c.ComponentID
                        select new { lc.InstallationFolder, c.ComponentID };
    }
}
```

I thought it was possible to make joins acrross multiple databases.